# Request filter not working in Jersey 2 on Embedded Jetty

Tags: java, jetty, jersey-2.0

I'm unable to get my request filter triggered. I run jetty 9.1 as an embedded server.

```
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class MyFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext arg0) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("HEY HO");
    }
}
```

I registered this class in the ResourceConfig, also tried to register the package. It's just ignored. Is it a bug, or am I missing something?

This is how I start Jetty:

```
Weld weld = new Weld();
WeldContainer container = weld.initialize();

URI baseUri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost/").port(8080).build();
ResourceConfig config = ResourceConfig.forApplicationClass(MyApplication.class);

Server server = JettyHttpContainerFactory.createServer(baseUri, config);
```

(MyApplication extends ResourceConfig and calls `this.package(...)` and `this.register(MyFilter.class)` in the constructor.

Comment: Can you show us how you configure/start Jetty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the class that defines the REST endpoint cannot be instantiated because - in my case - the instantiation depends on stuff that must be set up in the request filter.

However, the endpoint class is instanciated **before** the filter is called. In order to run the filter first, it has to be annotated `@PreMatching`.

```
@Provider
@PreMatching
public class MyFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Do you use this filter to provide custom injections or something like that?

Comment: I use it to initialize some thread locals (for instance, a counter that monitors the number of DB access triggered by the request).

Answer (score 0):

To enable cross-origin requests in a self-contained Jetty jar file with Jersey REST services (to allow calls from Swagger-UI). Create a CORSResponseFilter class:

```
public class CORSResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext)
        throws IOException {

    MultivaluedMap headers = responseContext.getHeaders();

    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    //headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://podcastpedia.org"); //allows CORS requests only coming from podcastpedia.org
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Codingpedia");
}
```

}

And reference it in your main App class:

```
public class App {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URI baseUri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost/").port(8080).build();
    ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig(API.class);
    config.register(CORSResponseFilter.class);
    Server jettyServer = JettyHttpContainerFactory.createServer(baseUri, config);

    try {
        jettyServer.start();
        jettyServer.join();
    } finally {
        jettyServer.destroy();
    }
}
```

}

By the similar way we have to embed the filter with jetty and jersey. hope this will use full.